# How to center align the actual TextBox in Asp.net website

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML/ASP code I want to center the TextBox on the display page. I am attaching my code below. Preferably I want to see the label beside the Textbox once it is in the center.

```
 <center>  <div class="container"  id="TextBox4" runat="server" width="181px"   bordercolor="Black" borderstyle="Solid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
         <p style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold; "> START DATE AND TIME&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:TextBox ID="Tb4" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="374px" style="text-align: center">
            </asp:TextBox></p>   
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
              $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
          });
      </script>
    </div>
  </div></center>
```

Comment: Are you trying to center-align horizontally, vertically, or both?

Comment: Do you get closer to what you want if you add `col-sm-offset-3` to you column div? (i.e. `<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>`). This will center that column. Also, you Bootstrap `input-group` component appears invalid. Please read what the valid markup is [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups). You have added a `<p>`, some text (your label), and an `<input />` in your `input-group` which might be invalid (the docs say "Textual <input>s only").

Comment: @Eli Horizontally

Comment: @zgood Yeah thanks for the feedback really helped I will refer the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code. I remove id=Tb4 width and Add some Class.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication11.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div class="container" id="TextBox4" runat="server" width="181px" bordercolor="Black" borderstyle="Solid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class='col-lg-12'>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                             &nbsp;
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                <div class="text-center">

                                      <p style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                                    START DATE AND TIME&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                          <asp:TextBox ID="Tb4" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  Style="text-align: center">
                                </asp:TextBox>
                                </p>
                                </div>


                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                             &nbsp;
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should look at [Bootstrap column offsets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting). There is no need to create empty `col-lg-4` columns and nesting everything in a `col-lg-12`, that's just extra markup with no value - you are just making your file size larger and harder to read lol

Comment: Thank your advice